# 'int' object has no attribute 'flatten'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a code this gives me a error saying `'int' object has no attribute 'flatten'`. I am using kmean algorithm for k=2 to cluster my data (passed as a list of data points).

```
import csv
import numpy as np
k=2
data=[23,43,67,89,1,10,101,243,34]
clusters = [[] for i in range(k)]
def kmeans(data, k):
    centroids = []
    centroids = randomize_centroids(data, centroids, k)  
    old_centroids = [[] for i in range(k)] 
    iterations = 0
    while not (has_converged(centroids, old_centroids, iterations)):
        iterations += 1
        clusters = euclidean_dist(data, centroids, clusters) # assign data points to clusters
        index =0   # recalculate centroids
        for cluster in clusters:
            old_centroids[index] = centroids[index]
            centroids[index] = np.mean(cluster, axis=0).tolist()
            index += 1
    print("The total number of data instances is: " + str(len(data)))
    print("The total number of iterations necessary is: " + str(iterations))
    print("The means of each cluster are: " + str(centroids))
    print("The clusters are as follows:")
    for cluster in clusters:
        print("Cluster with a size of " + str(len(cluster)) + " starts here:")
        print(np.array(cluster).tolist())
        print("Cluster ends here.")
# Calculates euclidean distance between
# a data point and all the available cluster
# centroids.    
def euclidean_dist(data, centroids, clusters):
    for instance in data:   # Find which centroid is the closestto the given data point.
        print("hello")
        mu_index = min([(i[0], np.linalg.norm(instance-centroids[i[0]])) \
                            for i in enumerate(centroids)], key=lambda t:t[1])[0]
        try:
            clusters[mu_index].append(instance)
        except KeyError:
            clusters[mu_index] = [instance]

    # If any cluster is empty then assign one point
    # from data set randomly so as to not have empty
    # clusters and 0 means.        
    for cluster in clusters:
        if not cluster:
           cluster.append(data[np.random.randint(0, len(data), size=1)].flatten().tolist())
    return clusters


# randomize initial centroids
def randomize_centroids(data, centroids, k):
    for cluster in range(0, k):
        print("hello")
        centroids.append(data[np.random.randint(0, len(data), size=1)].flatten().tolist())
    return centroids


# check if clusters have converged    
def has_converged(centroids, old_centroids, iterations):
    MAX_ITERATIONS = 1000
    if iterations > MAX_ITERATIONS:
        return True
    return old_centroids == centroids


if __name__=='__main__' :
    kmeans([23,43,67,89,1,10,101,243,34],2)
    print("hello")
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\shri ram\Desktop\summer_code_files\ddpcr_analysis.py", line 66, in 
>       kmeans([23,43,7,89,1,10,101,243,34,2],2)
>     File "C:\Users\shri ram\Desktop\summer_code_files\ddpcr_analysis.py", line 13, in kmeans
>
> clusters = euclidean_dist(data, centroids, clusters) # assign data points to clusters
>
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'clusters' referenced before assignment

Comment: `data[np.random.randint(0, len(data), size=1)].flatten()` so obviously `data` is an array of integers. you're not flattening the array. you're trying to flatten ONE element out of that array, which happens to be an int. and as the error says, you can't flatten an int.

Comment: Hi marc , Thanks for helping. I am new to python so i dont know much coding so what edit should i do then to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you tried apply `flatten` to one `int` element (not to numpy array). Try

```
centroids.append([data[np.random.randint(0, len(data), size=1)]])
```

instead of

```
centroids.append(data[np.random.randint(0, len(data), size=1)].flatten().tolist())
```

Also, you should move `clusters` initialization to `kmeans` function

```
...
def kmeans(data, k):
    clusters = [[] for i in range(k)]
    centroids = []
    centroids = randomize_centroids(data, centroids, k)  
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks kvorobiev, This bug is resolved but now this gives another error saying 'local variable 'clusters' referenced before assignment'. what should i do now ?

Comment: @Deepak Sharma Add full traceback to your question

Comment: Yeah I did . please see now

Comment: @Deepak Sharma You pass `clusters` variable to function without definition. You should add line like `clusters=[]` at the begining of `kmeans` function.

Comment: Its not working yet . Can you please try this it gives more errors